# How to get the 4th web element from a contextClick (Right Click) in selenium Automation

Tags: selenium, automation

How can i get the 4th web element after performing a contextClick? Soon right click is done the context menu gets closed so i cannot locate the 4th element.
Is there any way to right click on context menu and hold it for few seconds?
I am doing the test in Selenium 3.6 and FF 57.
When i ran the same script in chrome it worked fine.

Code:

```
WebElement rghtclk = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='QvFrame Document_CH08']/div[@class='QvContent']/div[@class='QvGrid']/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]"));
        Actions rghtactn = new Actions(driver);
        rghtactn.contextClick(rghtclk).perform();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Comment: Any way that you can give us the HTML? Your XPath is disgusting and usually there is enough uniqueness to not have to use that long xpath and make things a lot easier.

Comment: WebElement predictres = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='QvFrame Document_CH08']/div[@class='QvContent']/div[@class='QvGrid']/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div")); This is the custom xpath that i use and through FF firepath i was able to pin point to that xpath as well.

Comment: <ul class="ctx-menu popup-shadow ctx-menu-no-icons ctx-menu-contains-submenus" objtype="Grid">
<li class="cf ctx-menu-action- ctx-menu-has-submenu">
<li class="cf ctx-menu-action- ctx-menu-divider"/>
<li class="cf ctx-menu-action-PR">
<li class="cf ctx-menu-action-XL">
<a href="javascript:;">
<span class="ctx-menu-text">Send to Excel</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="cf ctx-menu-action-EC">
<li class="cf ctx-menu-action- ctx-menu-divider"/>
<li class="cf ctx-menu-action-MI">
<li class="cf ctx-menu-action-MA">
<li class="cf ctx-menu-action- ctx-menu-divider"/>
</ul>

Comment: I need my script to click on "Send to Excel". Since right click is not staying for a while i cannot point to that particular xpath

Comment: Rightclick stays only for a fraction of second and by that time i cannot click get the webelement for "Send to Excel"

Comment: Please edit your question and post all this additional information there rather than in comments so everyone can find the relevant info to answer the question.

Comment: You mention a context click menu... are you sure that it's HTML and not browser specific? Please post a link to the page with some steps you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: When i ran the script in chrome, it performed contextClick on that web element and i could see all the sub menu staying there for a while. Only in FF it just clicks and close. I believe its browser specific.